# How to inject a service in CustomReuseStrategy in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I have implemented CustomReuseStrategy in Angular. I want to subscribe to an observable in `shouldAttach()` to determine if the route should be reattached or not. I have created an observable in a service and I need to use the service instance in CustomReuseStrategy. I tried injecting the service in the constructor and I get this error:

> Can't resolve all parameters for CustomReuseStrategy

Should the constructor for the RouteReuseStrategy not have parameters? If so, how do I create the instance of the service?

Comment: What does your app module look like? Are you declaring your service in the `providers` array?

Comment: Yes. I have declared my service in the Providers array in appmodule. I could inject this service in other components and they are working fine. Since the "CustomReuseStrategy" is a class and not a component. I couldn't inject the service through the constructor.

Comment: Please, provide all relevant code. The question is off-topic without it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this by using Reflective Injector.

```js
let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([MyService]);
this.subscriptionSvc = injector.get(MyService);
```